# $\sigma$-algebras with a finite number of atoms

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{X}$ has a finite number of atoms. Is it true that this set of atoms partitions the space $\mathcal{X}$?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a sigma algbra without atoms and enlarge the space by adding a 'point at $\infty$' you get a sigma algebra with  a single atom. The atoms do not form a  partition in this case. 
 Ref: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22477/sigma-algebra-without-atoms

The answer is YES, if the sigma algebra is countably generated. In this case there are enough atoms and every set in the sigma algebra is a union of atoms.   Atoms are pair-wise disjoint. Since $\mathcal X$ belongs to the sigma algebra you can express it as  a union of atoms. Hence atoms form a  partition.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in general. There exist [sigma algebras without atoms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22477/sigma-algebra-without-atoms). 
Hence, the atoms cannot partition the space in general.